# Manually override feed element in settings using the FeedMe plugin

Tags: plugin-feedme

I'm fairly new to Craft so I could be missing out on some basics.

I need to import an events feed (xml) using the [FeedMe](https://github.com/engram-design/FeedMe) plugin. The feed has some Link tags.
Ex.

```html
<link rel="sales" type="text/html" href="[LINK TO TICKETSHOP]" />
<link rel="image" href="[LINK TO IMAGE]" />
```

I've got an Asset field but I can't properly set the Feed Element. It only shows `<link/@href>` or `<link/@type>`. If I select @href then it goes though all the elements with @href and generates a lot of errors because some aren't assets.

I've tried `<link/@rel="image">` in the default value field but then it imports the same value for all the Events. So all the Entries end up with the same image.

Is there a way to manually define the Feed Element?

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a bit of an issue with XML-based feeds. To Feed Me, both your node's are `link` nodes. They have different attributes for sure, but Feed Me doesn't identify nodes by their tag *and* attributes, so it'll look at all tags called `link` to get the image.

As you've stated, you'll be getting a bunch of errors due to this. Can you restructure your feed at all? The ideal method would be to rename one to `<image>` for instance.

Right now, there's no way to manually define field mapping, as its already complicated. You're more than welcome to submit a [feature request](https://github.com/engram-design/FeedMe/issues).

Comment: I stumbled upon this thread and was wondering if it has been added in the meantime...will feed me now work with attributes? Or is there a work around? I have a similar issue as Brad has... Thanks a lot, Wouter